# Wrong redirect after login -Java EE

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere

I've encountered a problem where after a user logs in the application, he gets redirected to the home page instead of the requested resource. I've checked the web.xml and found no misconfiguration.

Also searched the codebase for redirects/forwards, but found none.
The strange thing is that the url always has a hash mark in the middle. It's definetely not a url fragment, because the servlet's name is after it. I have no idea how it gets there, but I cannot reach the servlets without it. Google only gave me stuff about fragments.

I'm using websphere, which I'm fairly new to. Could it cause this?

Any thoughts on the issue?

Comment: You need to add some more information. What is the url you are trying to access, where you are redirected, web.xml. Do you have any filters defined?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response!
I still have no idea why that hash mark is in the middle of the URL, but this solved the problem:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Preserving+URL+anchor+fragments+on+login+form+submission

Have to handle these stuff client side (in this case JavaScript)